# Javascript: open background image in new window

Tags: javascript

I have some simple code that will open an embedded img in a new window:

```
<img onclick="window.open(this.src, 'child'); return true;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAYE">
```

Now I'm looking for the same trick but for a background image, I've tried this but backgroundImage is empty

```
<td onclick="window.open(this.style.backgroundImage, 'child');" background="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgA"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead declare your background as follows:

```
style="background-image: url(data:image ... );"
```

Beware, however, that if you intend to use larger images the URI you're going to try to open may be too large.

Comment: That works. Just need to strip the "url(" part of the string and it's good!

     onclick="window.open(this.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1), 'child');"

Answer (score 1):

You have to slice the image url from the background. As follows:

```
<td onclick="window.open(this.style.background.slice(4, -1), 'child'); return true;" style="background:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Big_smile.png')"></td>
```